# C# Regex validating input format

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input format like this:

```
{random string} + " " + {integer}
```

e.g.

```
a)    stringInput 43

b)    abcdefghijkl 89
```

How can I validate this format using Regex?

I am stuck on a problem:
what is the regular expression for string?

Comment: "string"? What kind of strings? What characters? An string could be whatever character. "123" is also a string. "  .<>" is also a string.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: What have you tried? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx regexpal.com

Comment: Why is it such a trend to rely on regex for *everything* when there are usually far more simpler solutions?

Comment: But are there any solutions for validating?

Comment: @BradM . . . regex can be pretty simple . . .

Comment: @MD.Unicorn any printable characters,thanks

Comment: You need to be `more specific` in regards to what you are trying to validate. are you wanting to allow `Alpha Numeric` chars ? are you wanting only numeric values..? are you wanting only ALPHA chars `A_Z,a-z` ......?? be more specific

Comment: "Any printable characters"? Is "4str.![] 12" valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public bool IsValidString(string s)
{
  string[] strs = s.Split(' ');
  int i = 0;
  if (strs.Length != 2)
    return false;
  return (int.TryParse(strs[1], out i);
}
```

You don't really need to use regex for this if you don't understand it, just an alternative method if you wanted to have a look. It may be easier to read, I personally find `Regex` very hard to read.

Comment: The questions says he wants a regex it could be done qithout it as anything that is done with regex can be done without it.

Comment: I agree, you definitely do not need the overhead of Regex to solve this problem.  This is much more computationally efficient and faster.  Just because somebody asks for regex doesn't mean that's the best answer. That's what SO is here for.

Comment: @Gabriel Monteiro Nepomuceno it's ok, as long as I can validate the input

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno The OP wants regex, most probably because they don't understand it. I have offered an alternative solution which may be easier for the OP to get along with and easier to read, as I said - only a suggestion.

Comment: @Downvoters When you downvote, give a reason at least. The OP has just said that any method is fine...

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try,

```
bool _result = Regex.IsMatch(yourStr, @"^[A-Za-z]+\s\d+$");
```

explaination of Regex Pattern,

sdf

- Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) `^`
- Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Za-z]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
  - A character in the range between “A” and “Z” `A-Z`
  - A character in the range between “a” and “z” `a-z`
- Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) `\s`
- Match a single digit 0..9 `\d+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) `$`

Comment: But your regular expression only apply for one character, if there are two or more characters, the regex won't work

Comment: It should match every printable character instead of only letters, except for this this is the best answer though

Answer (score 0):

should work

```
bool _result = Regex.IsMatch(yourStr,@"^\w+?.\d+?$");
```